# ios web response time slower than in android

Tags: ios, rest, nsurlsession

I am new to iOS development. Our organisation has a app in android and now we developed for iOS. The response time of the web calls in android, iOS version vary very much. Is this normal or is this the implementation fault? It is specially slow for chained calls during login. I am using NSURLSession for calls in iOS.
For ios this is my code:

```
let session = URLSession.init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    let url:URL = URL.init(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums")!
    let startDate = DispatchTime.now()
    let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest.init(url: url)
    session.dataTask(with: urlRequest)
    {
       data,response,error in

        let endDate = DispatchTime.now()
        print("For normal call====>\(Double(endDate.uptimeNanoseconds - startDate.uptimeNanoseconds)/1000000000)")
        let dataString = String.init(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        if dataString != nil
        {
            print(dataString!)
        }

    }.resume()
```

Response time is "For normal call====>2.045450472"

For android this is the code:

```
private String webUrl="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new RequestTask().execute();
    }
    class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try {
                URL url=new URL(webUrl);
                long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                double dif = end - time;
                System.out.print("=============>"+(double)(dif/1000));

                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = isw.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    data = isw.read();
                    System.out.print(current);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

For this output is: "=============>1.358"

My webcall Method:

```
func callHttpWebService(request : URLRequest , dataListener : DataProcessorListener? , responseListener : WebResponseListener)
    {
        //config.timeoutIntervalForRequest=10
        let session=URLSession.init(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let startTime = DispatchTime.now()
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
        {
            data, response, error in

            let endTime = DispatchTime.now()
            print("For \(responseListener)====> \(Double(endTime.uptimeNanoseconds - startTime.uptimeNanoseconds)/1000000000)")
            if error != nil
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    responseListener.onWebResponseFail()
                }
            }
            guard let httpResponse=response as? HTTPURLResponse else
            {
                return
            }
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200
            {
                guard let data=data else
                {
                    print("Error in webservice\(error)")
                    return
                }

                if ((httpResponse.url?.path.contains("branchImage"))! || (httpResponse.url?.path.contains("image"))! )
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async()
                    {
                    responseListener.showImageData!(data: data)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    let dataString = String.init(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                    if dataString != nil
                    {
                        print(dataString!)
                    }
                    if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                    {
                        if let dataListener=dataListener
                        {
                            if dataListener is StudentMarks || dataListener is IndividualAssessmentDataProcessor
                            {
                                let mainUrl=response?.url?.absoluteString
                                dataListener.getUrl!(url: mainUrl!)
                            }

                            dataListener.parseData(data: json as AnyObject)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async()
                                {
                                    let endTime2 = DispatchTime.now()
                                    print("Time between======>\(Double(endTime2.uptimeNanoseconds - endTime.uptimeNanoseconds)/1000000000)")
                                    responseListener.onWebResponseSuccess(dataListener: dataListener)
                                }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("Empty Data====>Session Expiry")
                        //responseListener.sessionExpiry!()
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async()
                {
                responseListener.onWebResponseFail()
                }
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing any code it is pretty much impossible to help here. For some information that is completely useless and probably irrelevant to your specific case, we have not seen this between Android and iOS. (Think about it for a second... do you really think that Apple would get away with a massive delay in any web responses after 10 years of iOS?)

Comment: ok then. I think its in my implementation. I will check my code once again

Comment: Look at what you are measuring in both cases. They are both completely different things. In Java you are streaming the data from the connection into a variable and storing it. You are measuring the time at the point of establishing the connection (and before any data is available). In iOS you are measuring the time after the connection has finished and is now closed and the data is available. That is not a fair race by any calculation.

Comment: How about stepping back from this for a second. What is the ACTUAL problem that you are experiencing here? Is there an unresponsive UI? Is the data not correct? Etc...

Comment: My problem is that response is slow in iOS app compared to android app for the same web calls

Comment: Have you seen that from just using the app? Is it noticeably quicker/slower on different devices? Or is that your conclusion from the measurement that you made (which we have established is not fair).

Comment: Have you tried to do request NOT on the main queue?

Comment: @NSDmitry ooh, good spot. I didn't actually notice that. If you are just going to use a standard configuration you would be better using... `URLSession.shared`

Comment: if i compare response time in both android and ios devices,everytime ios device is taking more time to deliver response

Comment: @BharathReddy please stop saying that. Already I have shown how your measurement is incorrect but also if you give your app to a user they will not have that timer. Is there something wrong with your app? Would an average user be able to see the delay? Also, did you just use the `shared` session like I suggested?

Comment: @BharathReddy so far you have not responded to any of the comments other than to repeat what you have said before. Please acknowledge that we are trying to help you. So far you have ignored everything that has been said.

Comment: i tried with URLSession.shared task still same result

Comment: @BharathReddy ok. Are you going to answer my question about the delay in the app? Are you going to acknowledge that what you are measuring in each platform is not the same thing?

Comment: I have added my code in the question. I am using delegates to pass data from this class to others. Am i doing something wrong here? response Listener is the class which called and dataListener is for parsing.

Comment: Thank You guys. I solved it. I set delegateQueue as nil and it is working very fast now

Comment: I'm also facing similar issue. iOS app is much slower than Android. @BharathReddy did you manage to fix it with setting delegateQueue to nil? Did you face any other issue with this settings?